# Iterating with my object stopped working

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

for some reason this code throws an error

```
// map<int, AnItem> roomlist;
// map<string, long> rinventory

map<int, AnItem>::iterator it;

for ( it = roomlist[roomno].rinventory.beg/in(); it != roomlist[roomno].rinventory.end(); it++ )    {

        if( (*it).second.name == "Stock" )
            tmpitem.append( strmug );
    }
```

The if statment throws the error.  It's really not that complex and I would think I could handle this.  So... roomlist is a map, roomno is an integer and rinventory is a map

```
class AnThing   {

public:
    AnThing();              // constructor
    string name;                // name reference
    int gtid;               // Thing ID
    string lcname;              // name in lowercase
    string m_name;
};

class AnItem : public AnThing   {

public:

    ItemType m_type;
    int imin;
    int imax;
    int ispeed;
    long unsigned iprice;
    unsigned int ecoin;
    GAttributes m_attributes;

    AnItem(); //Constructs an item with "invalid" values

    int& Min(); // Returns the min attribute
    int& Max(); // Returns the max attribute
    int& Speed(); // Returns the speed attribute

};
```

Thanks in advance!  I will append the errors I get below (there are two of them)

> c:\ucdhb2\gaia\logonserver\v6\gaiaserver.cpp(812) : error C2679:
>   binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of
>   type 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion) 1>        with 1>        [ 1>
>   _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits,std::allocator>,false> 1>        ] 1>        c:\program
>   files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xtree(498): could be
>   'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator
>   &std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator::operator =(const
>   std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator &)' 1>        with 1>        [ 1>
>   _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits,std::allocator>,false> 1>        ] 1>        while trying to match the
>   argument list '(std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator,
>   std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator)' 1>        with 1>        [ 1>
>   _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits,std::allocator>,false> 1>        ] 1>        and 1>        [ 1>
>   _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits,std::allocator>,false> 1>        ]
>   1>c:\ucdhb2\gaia\logonserver\v6\gaiaserver.cpp(812) : error C2678:
>   binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of
>   type 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion) 1>        with 1>        [ 1>
>   _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits,std::allocator>,false> 1>        ] 1>        c:\program files\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\guiddef.h(197): could be 'int operator
>   !=(const GUID &,const GUID &)' 1>        c:\program files\microsoft
>   visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xtree(314): or       'bool
>   std::_Tree<_Traits>::const_iterator::operator !=(const
>   std::_Tree<_Traits>::const_iterator &) const' 1>        with 1>
>   [ 1>
>   _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits,std::allocator>,false> 1>        ] 1>        while trying to match the
>   argument list '(std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator,
>   std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator)' 1>        with 1>        [ 1>
>   _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits,std::allocator>,false> 1>        ] 1>        and 1>        [ 1>
>   _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits,std::allocator>,false> 1>        ]

Comment: What is the type of `roomlist` and `rinventory`?

Comment: map<int, AnItem> roomlist;

map<string, long> rinventory;

Comment: Post them in the question, along with the definition of  `AnItem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iterator

```
map<int, AnItem>::iterator it;
```

needs to be of type

```
map<string, long>::iterator it;
```

based on your comment (i.e. you are iterating over `rinventory`, not `roomlist`).

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same errors + a new one error C2228: left of '.name' must have class/struct/union

Comment: I think something is very wrong in that loop: if you do intend to iterate over `rinventory` then `(*it).second` is a `long`, but you are asking for a member `name` from it. Can you think again about what you are trying to achieve in that code?

Comment: hmm, when I change the it to <string, long> it works fine!  but I still need to find the AnObjects I wanted to use in that loop :(  I think I can still make it happen.  If not I will return.  I really appreciate the help!